# Updating app display when website is updated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

I've got an audio playback application. I need to add a streaming feature which works in coordination with a website. Meaning, when a new file is added to the server and playable via the website, it should automatically become playable on the app. I do not want to hard code it into the app and am looking at making it dynamic. The only solution I can think of is linking the entries to a SQL database, however, the web developer has expressed security concern. He thinks allowing applications to connect to the db could pose a risk.

Any ideas on implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been to similar situation many times. A web Socket is the ideal solution for such cases. 
And the mobile should never connect to the db directly. the connection should be done , validated and monitored through a web service providing the Mobile with a RESTful Api.